# SVN only fails to commit new files that have been svn:copied with RA layer request failed error, changes and additions work fine

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2, svn

Whenever I try to commit a new file that has been created using svn:copy I get the following error:

```
RA layer request failed
Commit failed (details follow):
Unexpected HTTP status 502 'Bad Gateway' on
'/!svn/rvr/521/Project/trunk/image.png'
```

In the error above I did a `svn:copy` on `image.png` with `image2.png` as the new file. However, the error fails on `image.png` (it can't find it or something?).

Committing new files or changes to files works fine though.

The server is running on a raspberry pi 3b. The svn repository was created as follows:

```
svnadmin create /var/svn/Project
sudo chmod -R a+rwxX /var/svn
```

The server is running apache2 and the clients connect through a cloudflare tunnel. In apache2 I have configured `dav_svn.conf` as follows:

```
<Location / >
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /var/svn/Project

  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "SVN Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd

  Require valid-user

</Location>
```

This way I can access `domain.com/var/svn/Project` via just `domain.com`. Maybe that has something to do with this?

Any help is appreciated!

Edit:

I just tried committing a svn:copied file without cloudflare tunnel, which worked. So the issue has to do with cloudflare tunnel.

I will edit this once again if I ever find out how to fix the cloudflare tunnel issue.